# ItemAdding Event not firing

Tags: sharepoint-online, remote-event-receiver

I created an RER that updates a column when an Item is added, but it is not firing. I added an ItemAdded event and it fired

```
public SPRemoteEventResult ProcessEvent(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
        {
            SPRemoteEventResult result = new SPRemoteEventResult();

            if (properties.EventType == SPRemoteEventType.ItemAdding)
            {
                using (ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.CreateRemoteEventReceiverClientContext(properties))
                {
                    if (clientContext != null)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(properties.ItemEventProperties.ListTitle);
                            ListItem listItem = list.GetItemById(properties.ItemEventProperties.ListItemId);

                            listItem["SuccessAdding"] = "Yes Adding 4.0";
                            listItem.Update();
                            clientContext.Load(listItem);
                            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();



                            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have checked for the Item Adding in place of Item Added.

Change `if (properties.EventType == SPRemoteEventType.ItemAdding)` 
to

```
if (properties.EventType == SPRemoteEventType.ItemAdded)
```

And  your code will look like below

```
public SPRemoteEventResult ProcessEvent(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
    {
        SPRemoteEventResult result = new SPRemoteEventResult();

        if (properties.EventType == SPRemoteEventType.ItemAdded)
        {
            using (ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.CreateRemoteEventReceiverClientContext(properties))
            {
                if (clientContext != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(properties.ItemEventProperties.ListTitle);
                        ListItem listItem = list.GetItemById(properties.ItemEventProperties.ListItemId);

                        listItem["SuccessAdding"] = "Yes Adding 4.0";
                        listItem.Update();
                        clientContext.Load(listItem);
                        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();



                        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Well actually I tried ItemAdded and it works fine the difference is that when I use ItemAdded you have to refresh the page to see the result, I want to avoid that, that is why I use ItemAdding

Comment: As per the question asked and the snippet , provided the solution. However going forward please provide your challenges in the question, that will help other to understand the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you add remote ItemAdding ER to your list by `EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation`, you could use service bus to debug if any exception in your code.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/debug-and-troubleshoot-a-remote-event-receiver-in-a-sharepoint-add-in

[Refere here to create service bus in Azure portal](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-create-namespace-portal)

You could check my sample demo [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5b1aed4a-fb6e-414e-bfe5-7f14786cb659/remote-event-receiver-not-firing?forum=appsforsharepoint) also, hope it would help you.